# How to say "Kisses and hugs" in German?

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to write a letter to my close friend, who is German.
Basically, whenever the sentence in English is ended up with words:
"Kisses ad Hugs" it makes the intentions of the writer pretty obvious.

I am trying to build some similar sentence using German

Does "Küsse und Umarmungen.", as the ending sentence in a letter is grammatically correct?

Like:

> XXX
>   XXXXX
>   XXXXXX
>   Küsse und Umarmungen

I have a feeling that something is missing

Comment: I’d note that generally in English I’d expect to write it “Hugs and kisses” rather than “Kisses and hugs”.

Comment: *Gruß und Kuss*

Comment: @BernhardDöbler This should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does "Küsse und Umarmungen.", as the ending sentence in a letter is grammatically correct?

Yes it is grammatically correct. But the more common expression would be

> > Küsse und drück Dich

or

> > Küsse und umarme Dich

Answer (score 7):

I've never really read that in German. Most idiomatic to me feels

> Fühl dich gedrückt! (*Feel hugged*)

Comment: Nicht eher _"Fühl dich gedrückt und geküsst!"_?

Comment: If you want to add "geküsst" you can do that. I presume it's more a girly thing? I've never witnessed this among men.

Comment: _"I presume it's more a girly thing?"_ Hey it's world womens day today! Take care what you say. What makes you sure that OP's question was about conversations between men? It'ts quite common to see such phrase for a conversation between lovers (no matter if they're hetero or queer).

Comment: πάνταῥεῖ is right
I was creating a letter to my love (girl), it's a men-woman relation

Comment: I never assumed anything. You assume I did. I just say I never witnessed this among men so I presume it's a female thing. That doesn't imply that men don't, can't or shouldn't do it. It's just my own observation, which I clearly stated as such.

Comment: I see. That's also good to remember. Thank you for your help

Comment: I agree, and to me, even between men "fühl dich gedrückt" is restricted to situations in which the utterer wants to signal empathy for the addressee due to adverse circumstances that have affected the latter. But then again, this holds for "hug" in English as well.

Answer (score 6):

The most idiomatic word that comes to my mind to express this would use the word *knuddeln* (to cuddle or to hug). So you could write

> Ich knuddle Dich
>   Fühl Dich geknuddelt
>   `*knuddel*`

The last version uses chat slang to express the so-called *Inflektiv* which is the German equivalent of the English inifinitve without "to".